# Mouth as Mountain?

Tags: synonyms, archaicisms

"The "MS. Found in a Bottle," was originally published in 1831, and it was not until many years afterwards that I became acquainted with the maps of Mercator, in which the ocean is represented as rushing, by four **mouths**, into the (northern) Polar Gulf, to be absorbed into the bowels of the earth; the Pole itself being represented by a black rock, towering to a prodigious height." (Source: [Ms. Found in a Bottle](http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/790/))

In the context of the particular map in question (which might not conform to present-day, common-place usage), does **mouth** mean **mountain**, or **mount**?

Comment: That's not quite how it works. The English words _mouth_ and _mountain_ are both descended from the same [Proto-Indo-European root, _*men-²_](http://web.archive.org/web/20080629193724/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE321.html), but they do not mean the same thing anymore. They both **do** still refer to things that are prototypically three-dimensional, but one is concave while the other is convex. This is normal enough in semantic history.

Comment: Thank you. I can imagine they no longer mean the same thing. But they do mean the same thing in Poe's story, don't they? When he says "by four mouths," he actually means mountain (or mount), correct?

Comment: Ask Poe. I never predict anything, especially the past.

Comment: I think he means *mouths*. Look it up in the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mouth). *3. : something that resembles a mouth especially in affording entrance or exit: as
a : the place where a stream enters a larger body of water
b : the surface opening of an underground cavity*.

Comment: If you look at a [Map of Mercator](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Mercator_1569.png) you can imagine "the ocean is ... rushing, by four mouths, into the (northern) Polar Gulf". (More maps available by 'googling' "maps of mercator").

Comment: Can you explain why you think mountain' is relevant? Can an ocean rush into something via mountains or via mouths?

Answer (score 4):

No, it means mouth, as in mouth of a river.